# Интерактивный режим для Explicit тестов

Tags: c#, nunit, rider

Часто использую тесты Nunit в качестве песочницы.

```
[TestFixture, Explicit]
public class SandBox{
    [Test]
    public void FooTest()
    {
        // Assert'ов нет. Только наброски кода //
    }
}
```

Т.е. запускаю и смотрю по логам что там произошло. Но Rider пишет логи только после принудительной остановки теста, что не очень удобно. Есть ли возможность запускать такие тесты в интерактивном режиме, чтобы сразу видеть консольный вывод?

Comment: Не ответ, просто хочу поделиться. Я для маленьких скриптов использую LinqPad- пользуюсь им уже лет 6-7, очень удобно

Comment: Я просто создаю консольное приложение для такой цели. На мой взгляд, удобнее и работает быстрее.

Comment: tym32167, тут речь скорее о части большого проекта, которую хочется запустить в консолеподобном режиме, чтобы видеть логи в реальном времени, а не после остановки теста. За ответ спасибо

Comment: Alexander Petrov, в общий гит не запушить, т.к. будет сильно выбиваться из общего кодстайла.